# Displaying JSON server response on client side without JQuery

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to make a function that gets the server response(JSON) and displays the information from the JSON in a list on the webpage without using JQuery. How would that be possible?

```
filterGet: function () {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

        ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200)
            {

                var ul = document.getElementById("results");
                while(ul.firstChild){
                    ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
                }

                //i am trying to get the JSON response from the server
                var array = ajax.response;



                var i;
                for(i=0;array.length;i++){

                    var latitudeForm = array[i].Latitude;
                    var longitudeForm = array[i].Longitude;
                    var nameForm = array[i].TagName;
                    var hashForm = array[i].HashName;

                    var newli = document.createElement('li');
                    newli.className = "tagListElements";
                    newli.innerText = nameForm + "("  + latitudeForm + ","
                        + longitudeForm + ")" + hashForm;
                    ul.appendChild(newli);
                }

            }
        }

        ajax.open('GET', "/test1" , true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        ajax.send();
    }
```

With Postman i get the following "GET" body:

```
[
{
    "Latitude": "45.01379",
    "Longitude": "4.390071",
    "TagName": "Casel",
    "HashName": "#begaiburje"
},
{
    "Latitude": "59.01379",
    "Longitude": "7.390071",
    "TagName": "Casel",
    "HashName": "#ne"
}
]
```

[The output is just for presentation purposes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8D85.png)

Simply put I want to achieve the following but without the usage of JQuery:

```
var main = function() {
    "use strict";
    var addTodosToList = function(todos) {
        var todolist = document.getElementById("todo-list");
        for (var key in todos) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = "TODO: " + todos[key].message;
            todolist.appendChild(li);
        }
    };
    $.getJSON("todos", addTodosToList);
}
$(main);
```

Comment: There's no jQuery in your code right now, what's the current output? What's the specific problem you're running into?

Comment: Have you debugged to see what properties are available on the `ajax` variable.  The data may not be in `response` and may be in `responseText`, I forget.  But in any case, it will most likely still be a string and you will need to use `JSON.parse()` to convert it to the array.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks! It worked! You saved the day!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to use the `Content-type` request header. Instead, between opening the XHR and sending it, you would set `ajax.responseType = 'json'`, as per this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType

Without setting `responseType`, the default return type is plain text, so you could also leave it as-is and just add a `JSON.parse` into your callback to convert the string JSON into an object... but why do that when `responseType` exists? :D

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted? Ultimately, the OP did end up parsing the `responseText`, like I mentioned, though `responseType` would be a little easier.

Comment: I used the answer of Taplar, but yours was also what i needed! Thank you as well!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to use "innerHtml" to place your json response inside your html page.

Reference:

[javascript - Using innerHTML to display JSON/object data in a certain div - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068054/using-innerhtml-to-display-json-object-data-in-a-certain-div)

[JSON XMLHttpRequest](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_http.asp)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please provide a code sample to enhance your answer? This will make it more useful to future readers.